# Referencing a calculated column in the where clause SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This line of code is a snippet from my select statement.

```
frdFreedays - DateDiff(dd,conReceiptToStock,GetDate()) As FreeDaysRemaining
```

Below is a snippet from my where clause

```
and frdFreedays - DateDiff(dd,conReceiptToStock,GetDate()) <= @intFreeDays
```

The question I have is how can I reference the FreeDaysRemaining column and so I can compare it to @`intFreeDays`

I am looking for something like this

```
Freedays <= @intFreeDays
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to Aaron's answer, you could use a common table expression:

```
;with cte_FreeDaysRemaining as
    (
        select
            frdFreedays - DateDiff(dd,conReceiptToStock,GetDate()) As FreeDaysRemaining
            --, more columns
        from yourtable
    )
    select
        FreeDaysRemaining
        --, more columns
    from cte_FreeDaysRemaining
    where FreeDaysRemaining <= @intFreeDays
```

Comment: Any input on why this is the better choice? :)

Comment: None, other than my personal preference is to use a CTE rather than a derived table.

Answer (score 23):

You can't reference an alias anywhere except `ORDER BY`. One workaround (aside from the obvious possibility of repeating the expression) is to put it in a derived table:

```
SELECT FreeDaysRemaining --, other columns
FROM
(
  SELECT frdFreedays - DATEDIFF(DAY, conReceiptToStock, GETDATE()) AS FreeDaysRemaining
    --, other columns
  FROM ...
) AS x
WHERE FreeDaysRemaining <= @intFreeDays;
```

Comment: This is crazy to thing that there is no solution other than this. Having a specific statement to add condition on the resultset would be simple to create (I think). There is the `HAVING` for aggregate function, why not a `FILTER` for the resultset. Ok, this would be a third statement in a query, kind of messy but when you have a select with 20 column to write twice because of a simple condition, this is really messy and a pain in the *** to maintain.

Comment: Ditto to AxelH's comments.  It's 2008 and there should be a better way by now.