# How to filter data in a WHERE clause based on a derived column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I'd like to have a WHERE clause on a column that is derived.

I have something like this:

```
SELECT ActualColumn1, 
CASE WHEN condition THEN value1 ELSE value2 AS DerivedColumn1
FROM
...
WHERE
DerivedColumn1 <> 'Foo' -- I'd like to filter on the derived column
```

Running this query reports the error "Invalid column name DerivedColumn1".

Comment: You have to rewrite the statement in the `where` clause again or use a subquery to refer to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot refer to an alias from the `WHERE` directly (you *could* from the `ORDER BY`) , you have to use a sub-query or CTE (or repeat the `CASE WHEN` in the `WHERE`):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ActualColumn1, 
    CASE WHEN condition THEN value1 ELSE value2 AS DerivedColumn1
    FROM
    ...
)
SELECT ActualColumn1, DerivedColumn1 
FROM CTE
WHERE DerivedColumn1 <> 'Foo'
```

Related:  [Reference alias (calculated in SELECT) in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182339/reference-alias-calculated-in-select-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 2):

You can't, but you can put case in a subquery or in a common table expression.

Check also this question for more information:

[Referencing a calculated column in the where clause SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720790/referencing-a-calculated-column-in-the-where-clause-sql)

Answer (score 2):

Although the derived column is not available to you directly, you have several ways of achieving the desired result:

1. **Use the same expression directly** - This is not ideal because you need to repeat yourself, but for small expressions it is often acceptable
2. **Wrap a select inside another select** - This approach lets you filter on the columns of the inner select in the `WHERE` clause of the outer select.
3. **Use [*Common Table Expression*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)** - This approach is similar to the above in that it lets you wrap a select inside another structure (CTE) on which you can use named columns.

Here is an illustration of the last approach:

```
WITH CTE (ActualColumn1, DerivedColumn1)
AS
(
    SELECT ActualColumn1,
    CASE WHEN condition THEN value1 ELSE value2 AS DerivedColumn1
    FROM ...
)
SELECT ActualColumn1, DerivedColumn1
FROM CTE
WHERE DerivedColumn = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ActualColumn1, 
CASE WHEN condition THEN value1 ELSE value2 AS DerivedColumn1
FROM
...
) Z
WHERE
DerivedColumn1 <> 'Foo'
```

**NOTE:**
If you use subquery , giving **ALIAS** name to subquery is **compulsory** as shown above- **Z** otherwise error will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it directly, but you can do like this:

```
select * from
(
SELECT ActualColumn1, 
CASE WHEN condition THEN value1 ELSE value2 AS DerivedColumn1
FROM
...
)
WHERE
DerivedColumn1 <> 'Foo' -- I'd like to filter on the derived column
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT tbl.ActualColumn1, cap.DerivedColumn1
FROM ... as tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN condition THEN value1 ELSE value2 END) AS cap(DerivedColumn1)
WHERE cap.DerivedColumn1 <> 'Foo'
```